# Mongodb connection suddenly stopped working with "Bad Auth" error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So mongoose was working just fine for more than 2 months, but suddenly crashed with this error

```
/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:210
                    callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
                             ^
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:210:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:777:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' }
}
```

Anyone knows what is the issue?
My IP is configured as access from anywhere correctly
Using connection to application, my uri is well configured and copy pasted to my project, and again the connection was perfect for 2months but stopped out of nowhere

Comment: check if you have missed anything in the uri

Comment: @cmgchess nothing is missing it was working perfectly and no one changed the uri since day 1

Comment: try connecting to db using mongoshell. (eg ```$ mongo "mongodb://user@pass:localhost/dbname" ```)

Comment: or did you accidently add an extra whte space at the ends or something

Comment: @cmgchess I didnt, but now I created a new user, added the username and password and then changed back to the main user